# How to show months and year together in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am making a calculator that calculates the age in years but I also want to calculate months Please help me with this Regard Thank you. I want my output like this for 22 years and 3 months. I attach my javascript code and Razor view code. In javascript code, only years are calculated and in Razor view, two text boxes in the first text box take the user's DOB and show his age in the other text box. I want to add a code to calculate months also.DOB is not hardcode .

```
<html>

<body> 
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" asp-for="Dob">Birth date:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5"> 
            <input asp-for="Dob" id="txtDOB" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" /> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Age">Age:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" id="age" asp-for="Age" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html> 

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtDOB").change(function () {
        var dob = $("#txtDOB").val();

        if (dob == null || dob == "") {

        } else {
            $("#age").val(getAge(dob));
        }
    });

    function getAge(birth) {
        ageMS = Date.parse(Date()) - Date.parse(birth);
        age = new Date();
        age.setTime(ageMS);
        ageYear = age.getFullYear() - 1970;

        return ageYear;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#. You wrote JS Code to get the age. You can calculate the age in months and devide by 12 to get years, then modulo to get the months.

Comment: but I want years and months (22 years 5 months) How to do this ?.

Comment: Hello Did you had a chance to try the soltuion? Do you need any further assistance on it?

Comment: I tried but      CalulateAgeFromDob action method is not called  but it is not called.@MdFaridUddinKiron

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the difference in months (total months):

```
function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth();
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```

Use devision (by 12) to get the full years difference, then use modulo to get the remaining months.

```
var totalMonths = monthDiff(d1, d2);
var years = Math.floor(totalMonths / 12);
var months = totalMonths % 12;
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v0dn64rk/

Comment: it calculates automatically after the user enter the DOB and text box gives the result How to do that?

Comment: So you want to listen on the textbox change to automatically trigger the calculation? This is not stated in the question. Subscribe to the `onchange` event of the textbox.

Comment: I want when the user to enter the DOB at run time and then the text box to show the age. In this code, DOB is hard to code.var birth = new Date("08 Nov 2020 00:00:00 GMT");

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiron it's not working only an error alert is shown after entering the date.

Comment: What error is shown? When you use this answer or the one from @Md Farid Uddin Kiron?

Comment: no error is shown only an alert is shown function is not called I think

Comment: Why calculate Age method is working please help me ...

Comment: your code is working but how to use this code dynamically that it uses today's date automatically and gives the age in years and month.

Answer (score 0):

> I want when the user to enter the DOB at run time and then the text
> box to show the age. In this code, DOB is hard to code.var birth = new
> Date("08 Nov 2020 00:00:00 GMT")

Based on your code and comment It seems that you are trying to calculate age what user select in calender and calculate the age autometically along with the month. You can do that both using `C#` and `Javascript`. Here is the elegant way to do that using `C#`, `Jquery` and `Ajax` which is more easy and flexible in ragards of formating.

**Calculate Age Method:**

```
public object CalculateAge(DateTime dateOfBirth)
        {
            //DateTime birth = new DateTime(1988, 08, 02);
            DateTime birth = dateOfBirth;
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan span = today - birth;
            DateTime age = DateTime.MinValue + span;

            // Make adjustment due to MinValue equalling 1/1/1int years = age.Year - 1;
            int months = age.Month - 1;
            int days = age.Day - 1;

            // Print out not only how many years old they are but give months and days as well
            var ageInYMD = string.Format("{0} years, {1} months, {2} days", age.Year, months, days);
            var ageInYM = string.Format("{0} years, {1} months", age.Year, months);
            var ageInY = string.Format("{0} years", age.Year);

            return ageInYM;
        }
```

**Note:** Importantly it will provide you more flexibility to format the date as you want.

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult ViewCalculateAgeJquery() // This is to load view
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CalulateAgeFromDob(DateTime dateOfBirth) // This controller will be called once the age selected.
        {
            var age = CalculateAge(dateOfBirth);
            return Json(age);
        }
```

**View:**

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.CalculateAgeModel
<div>
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th> <label asp-for="DoB"></label></th>
            <td> <input asp-for="DoB" id="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter date of birth" /><span asp-validation-for="DoB"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <label asp-for="Age"></label></th>
            <td> <input asp-for="Age" id="Age" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="Calculated age" /><span asp-validation-for="Age"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $('#dateOfBirth').change(function () {

                var dateOfBirth = $('#dateOfBirth').val();

                console.log(dateOfBirth);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/CalculateAge/CalulateAgeFromDob',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#Age").val(response);
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error!');
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class CalculateAgeModel
    {
        public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

It will help you to implement as per your requirement.

Comment: Why do you "convert" the `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime`? Isn't it unnecessary since you can get the `year` and `month` component from `TimeSpan`?

Comment: Well, if you test this case `var birth = new Date("08 jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");` your code will produce `Years: 22.833333333333332 Months: 10` which is not expeted in case of `date of birth` calculation nonetheless, I have implemented that. Hope its now clear. You can test all possible way using my code. Always produce correct output. Let me know if any further explanation required, would love to assist on this.

Comment: I was confused, because of the conversion from `TimeSpan` to `DateTime` in your C# Code. But now I get that you use it because `TimeSpan` does not provide Year and Month. Also edited my answer thanks to your comments :) I still think a server roundtrip to calculate the age is a bit "overkill" but your solution works!

Comment: Thanks for your response, as for age there is a twist which somewhat little hassle in javascript.